How to bind a custom compile command to a key?
In my .emacs file,I want to pass the current buffer file name to an external bash compile script called, "com", and bind it to a keyboard key, preferably, Ctrl-F5.
I have tried several attempts without success. Not an expert on the syntax of the .emacs file

You write an interactive function (aka command) that does what you want and bind it to a key:
  (defun my/command ()
    (interactive)
    (shell-command (format "com %s" (buffer-file-name))))

  (define-key global-map (kbd "C-<f5>") #'my/command)

Assuming that com is in a directory somewhere in your PATH that Emacs knows about, that should be enough.
